# ConvertToGL()......Cocos 2dx

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

```
 CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( touches->anyObject() );
 CCPoint location = touch->locationInView();
 location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
```

Could anybody explain me what is that method for and why is neccesary to use!?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIKit coordinates have the Y coordinate starting in the top left. OpenGL has the Y coordinate start from the bottom left.

`convertToGL()` simply converts a top left coordinate system into a bottom left coordinate system by subtracting the Y coordinate from the height of the screen.

Another note, cocos2d is completely open source, if you want to know what a function does, just have a look at the source code.